# Updating openssl to fix heartbleed bug tries to remove redis-server

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, redis, heartbleed

I am trying to fix openssl heartbleed bug on my server. I read that I can update the openssl version with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl1.0.0
```

But when i try to run this command i get error like this:

> libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.10) but 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.17 is to be installed 
>    redis-server : Depends: redis-tools (= 2:2.8.9-1chl1~precise1) but 2:2.8.12-1chl1~precise1 is to be installed

and it asks me to run 'apt-get -f install'. When i try to run this command it tries to remove the redis-server. I cannot remove redis-server as my web app needs it. This is the error i get:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>     redis-server
>   The following held packages will be changed:
>     redis-server

Is there any way to fix the heartbleed without removing the redis-server. I tried to hold the package using:

```
sudo apt-mark hold redis-tools redis-server
```

It holds the package but when I try to run sudo apt-get -f install to fix the openssl issue it still tries to remove the redis-server with same message as above.

Please help. Is there a way to fix heartbleed without removing redis-server and without recompiling the openssl.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this? And why did you hold redis-server?

Comment: Also, Is there some reason why you aren't doing `apt-get dist-upgrade` to just update all your software?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS, i hold it so that it doesn't get removed when updating. I hope that's what its for. But it still tries to remove redis-server when updating.

Comment: No, why did you hold redis-server _before_ this issue ever arose? You should remove the hold and try again.

Comment: Where did you get redis from?  There doesn't appear to be a 12.04 version of redis that includes a package named `redis-tools`.  I would guess whatever unofficial repo you are using isn't being properly maintained or something and is incompatible with an updated version of ssl.  Find a new source for redis.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it was the same issue before hold as well. So i tried to add mark the package as hold so it doesn't remove but that didnt help..

Comment: You really should update the whole system. OpenSSL touches too much.

Comment: @MichaelHampton When you say 'touches too much'?  What does that exactly mean?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Also if i update the whole system there will be compatibility issues. Also I think it will remove the redis-server which I cannot allow.